# Changing main wiki

Tags: xwiki

I have two wikis in xwiki. One main and and a secondary. I want to delete the main and make the secondary the main on so that after login I see the secondary (and main is deleted).

But xwiki does not let me to delete the main wiki. I haven't seen any option to select (promote) the secondary wiki to the main one.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

It's not supported, just setup a new instance and copy your subwiki's data to the new instance's main wiki.

Long answer:

There is something in XWiki that you can use, which is to set in `xwiki.cfg` the `xwiki.db` property to use the database of the subwiki as main wiki. As an alternative, you could just do that at a database level and swap the database names between the main wiki (`xwiki`) and the subwiki.

With this, your main wiki will still be called `xwiki`, but its contents will be that of the subwiki you have just "promoted". Depending on which of the 2 options you took, the old main wiki's contents might or may not still be accessible.

However, there are still a lot of problems to fix because the new main wiki will be missing some extensions that were previously installed just at the main wiki level, like wiki manager application (to manage subwikis) and others. Also, global users and wiki descriptors were on the old main wiki, so unless you move/copy those by hand before doing the switch, you might not be able to log in with your users or not be able to access your subwikis.

Even if you fix that, the biggest problem is the Extension Manager index/local repository which is stored in the permanent directory and which does not know about the switch you just did. This means that it will still report that some extensions are installed on the new main wiki when, in fact, he are not (they are only installed on the old main wiki you have just switched out), so things might start to behave badly. This is very complicated to fix and I'm not going to try to go into the details.

At this point, I believe that the best recommendation I could make is to setup a fresh installation of XWiki and manually export the changes and data you need from the 1st installation's subwiki and import it on the new installation's main wiki. This helps you avoid a lot of headaches in dealing with XWiki internal details that are very easy to screw up.